# Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

My app works in the browser, but it doesn't work when I try to build .apk file.

Can someone help?

Please see below.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.376 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

  > [com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.0] C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Starttwo\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.firebase\firebase-common\19.3.0\AndroidManifest.xml:32:9-36:35: 
  >   Error: Invalid instruction 'targetApi', valid instructions are : REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT

Ionic:

Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.0.1
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (10 plugins total)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.11.0
   native-run  : not installed

System:

NodeJS : v11.3.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 4.6.1
   OS     : Windows 10

Comment: Without having access to the full code, it is hard to tell. Still, based on the error message, only it looks like within your ```AndroidManifest.xml``` file you have somewhere in there the value ```targetApi``` where it should not be because the only acceptable possible values are either REMOVE, REPLACE, or STRICT.

Comment: node v11 has not npm 4.6 (but 6.x), I would check your node installation